# Output skew when using clocking blocks

Tags: verification, system-verilog, uvm

I am using a clocking block in my interface for signal aliasing. I want to concatenate some of the bits together to form a bus, and then drive this bus from my driver. So, for example:

```
interface bus_intf (clk);
    input logic      clk;
          logic[1:0] x_lsb;
          logic[1:0] x_msb;

   clocking driver_bus @(posedge clk)
      default input #1step output #0;
      output x_bus = {x_msb, x_lsb};
   endclocking
endinterface
```

Now the problem with this is, in one of my assertions, I need to read **bus_intf.driver_bus.x_bus**. As stated in the SV manual, an output variable from a clocking block should not be read by the testbench, and if it is, then simulator spits out an error (or warning in my case).

So I modified the interface:

```
interface bus_intf (clk);
    input logic      clk;
          logic[1:0] x_lsb;
          logic[1:0] x_msb;

   clocking driver_bus @(posedge clk)
      default input #1step output #0;
      inout x_bus = {x_msb, x_lsb};
   endclocking
endinterface
```

The problem now is, in my waveform I see two signals being created - **x_bus** and **x_bus__o**. I understand why Questasim did this - it is to separate the **inout** declaration so I can view both versions.
However, the problem now is all my clocking drive is delayed by one clock cycle! so **x_bus__o** which is connected to the DUT is one clock cycle later than **x_bus**. This is inspite of me explicitly stating that output skew is #0.

Any idea why this happens? Am I doing something wrong or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put your code on EDAPlayground and tried it out. It seems to be working as expected. Here's my test harness:

```
module top;
  bit clk;
  always #1 clk = ~clk;

  bus_intf busif(clk);

  initial begin
    @busif.driver_bus;
    $display("time = ", $time);
    busif.driver_bus.x_bus <= 'hf;

    repeat (2)
      @(negedge clk);
    $display("time = ", $time);
    busif.driver_bus.x_bus <= 'ha;

    #100;
    $finish();
  end

  always @(busif.x_lsb)
    $display("time = ", $time, " x_lsb = ", busif.x_lsb);

  always @(busif.x_msb)
    $display("time = ", $time, " x_msb = ", busif.x_msb);
endmodule
```

The link is here if you want to try it online: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Utf

If I drive `x_bus` at a posedge, then the value will be written immediately, as would be expected due to the `#0` output delay. If I drive `x_bus` at a negedge (or at any other time aside from a posedge), then it will wait until the next posedge to drive the value. I see this behavior regardless of whether `x_bus` is declared as `output` or `inout`.

Check to see when you are scheduling your writes; this might be the reason you see some delays on your waves.

Answer (score 0):

When you have bidirectional flow through a clocking block, the signal from the verification to the hardware and back has to go through two virtual D-FFs. So the original observation is correct. The input of 1-step is one D-FF to the design; then the return is one more D-FF back appearing 0ns (i.e., just after the clock). Clocking blocks are not useful in the situation of a signal that requires a single-cycle turn-around, and for that reason, you avoid them if that is a requirement. For most designs, it is simply not necessary. Monitors will observe the signals with a pipeline delay of one cycle, which is generally not a problem.